# Make a panel resizable to the user

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have 1 panel in windows form, set to a certain width and height, and want to recreate something similar to how you can adjust width and the height the paint box in Microsoft paint. How do I make a panel resizable for the user, so that they can resize from both width and height?

Comment: This depends on the layout of your form. Please add a picture with your layout.

Comment: You have to use some thumbs/handles ( simple user control ) and set them on the panel corners and in the middle of the edge. Then you just create some drag mechanizm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your own `UserControl` (e.g. called `ResizablePanel`), use a `Panel` in it, set its `Anchor` to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`.

Resize that `Panel` so it nearly covers all the corners of your `UserControl`. The black part in this picture is the `UserControl`, the white part, your `Panel`.

[image: Example ResizablePanel]

Then you have to use 3 Events: `ResizablePanel_MouseDown`, `ResizablePanel_MouseMove` and `ResizablePanel_MouseUp`.

```
private void ResizablePanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        isResizeMode = true;
    }
}

private void ResizablePanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isResizeMode)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(e.X, e.Y);
    }
}

private void ResizablePanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        isResizeMode = false;
    }
}
```

Now you can click on your `ResizablePanel` border to resize it directly.

[image]

Comment: Woaah, that GIF . _(Gruß aus Göppingen!)_

Comment: Haha, I have to admit, that this enhances the question quite a bit (*Grüße zurück aus Stuttgart!*)

Comment: @Janes Abou Chleih Thanks a lot! I did exactly what you said in your post, and it definitely helped me

Comment: @hindstrust You're welcome. If you think that this is an answer to your question and helped you, you can mark it as accepted with the green check under the up- and downvote buttons. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Is it also possible to reverse the resizing? So that the panel sticks to the right and resizes to the left?